# Is it ok to put canonical tags on 301 redirected pages?

Tags: seo, 301-redirect, rel-canonical

I redirected my e-commerce website from Http to Https. Now I want to implement canonical tags for similar products to avoid duplicate issue. In my product pages the permalink is the HTTP version but the redirection works properly. Is it ok if I put the canonical tag in a 301 redirected page? Since I can not find the HTTPs pages in my Wordpress.

Comment: How would you do that?   Redirects don't have a "page", so you can't put a canonical tag in the same URL that redirects.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller: You could do so by adding the canonical "tag" to the http header. But I would not do this as the 301 redirect should go to the "final" URL anyway.

Comment: I didn't even know there was a HTTP header for that.  I found documentation from Google about it: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en&rd=1#rel-canonical-header-method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not correct. You should only use [canonical tag](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en) for the final URL you want Google to crawl.

> Google will choose one URL as the canonical version and crawl that,
>   and all other URLs will be considered duplicate URLs and crawled less
>   often.

So, if you use a `301 redirect` from http to https and after that tells Google that the canonical URL is the previous one, that could lead to an indexation problem. I'll not take the risk.

Comment: So how can I implement the canonical links while the permalink is HTTP in product pages?

Comment: You need to change all the links on your site to point to HTTPS.  There are probably links in your WordPress database.