# Duplicate content after moving from http to https

Tags: google-search-console, htaccess, https, canonical-url, rel-canonical

- I move my wordpress blog from "http" to "https".
- I generate a sitemap that contains canonical urls with "https" and
  submit it to GSC.
- I used "rel=canonical" tag in all blog post urls.
- I also implement "301 redirect" via "htaccess" file at the same time
  with "rel=canonical" tag but after quick research it seems it is not
  recommended.

Although I declare my urls as "https", Google keeps displaying "Standard URL chosen by Google" as "http" version of url and saying that "URL is not on Google" "Duplicate, submitted URL not selected as canonical".

What am I missing I did comprehensive search on the web and implement every possible scenario, but I couldn't be able to get my urls as indexed properly.any suggestions?

Comment: Where have you read that "it is not recommended" to implement the "301 redirect"? Have you confirmed that all steps are working as intended and that the redirect is redirecting correctly? In GSC are you submitting the HTTPS sitemap to the HTTPS property? The HTTP sitemap can remain in place on the HTTP property.

Comment: @MrWhite What is not recommended is not tou use rel=canonical tag and 301 redirect at the same time I saw this:  https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/117709/is-it-ok-to-put-canonical-tags-on-301-redirected-pages I'm sure that https sitemap is under https property in gsc. What would you recommend?

Comment: The question you link to is setting the HTTP URL as `rel=canonical` _but_ redirecting to HTTPS which is indeed incorrect (the canonical tag will most likely get ignored in that instance) - that is not what you are doing (you are setting HTTPS as canonical and redirecting to HTTPS - the same, ie. you are redirecting to the canonical URL.) It sounds like you have done everything correctly. If the redirect is implemented correctly then there is no _duplicate content_. (However, I didn't think that Google would flag HTTP and HTTPS versions of the same URL as "duplicate content"?)

Comment: If this is something you have only just implemented then it will take time for Google/GSC to update.

Comment: I implemented couple of days ago but nothing changed google still chosen http version of url but show https version as "declared by user". so I decided ro revert back the 301 redirect just use rel=canonical now I understand from your comments that I should use 301 redirect for every page (blog posts) to eliminate duplicate content is it true? after doing that should I do anything on GSC ?

Answer (score 4):

You just need to give it time.   A couple days is no where near enough.  Google will move your site over to HTTPS in its search index one page at a time.  Depending on the size of your site, the process could take up to a year.  See [HTTP to HTTPS: Wait for new sitemap to be indexed?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/110067/http-to-https-wait-for-new-sitemap-to-be-indexed/110084#110084)

In addition, rankings sometimes worsen in Google when redirecting to HTTPS.   It seems to be safer to run HTTP and HTTPS together for a year without redirecting between them, but declaring the canonical URLs to be HTTPS.  See [Huge drop [50%] in traffic after HTTPS move](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/78820/huge-drop-50-in-traffic-after-https-move)